# What is the chance a dodge will trigger Backlash?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

When using the Backlash rune for Mantra of Evasion, what does "a chance" mean?

> Successfully dodging an attack has a chance to create a burst of flame dealing X% weapon damage as Fire to all nearby enemies.

Comment: for some reason I thought it was 50%, but I can't find the source

Comment: after playing around with it more, I think it triggers 100% of the time, but has a cooldown during which it can't trigger no matter how often you dodge.  I'll do some more testing later.

Comment: @yx. very interesting.  I look forward to hearing more.

Answer (score 1):

No one (outside of Blizzard) knows currently. There are other abilities that simply say "a chance to..." for other classes too.

Hopefully when the Diablo 3 official game guide on the battle.net site gets updated from its current state of "basic" to some sort of "advanced", questions like this will be answered.

Comment: I wouldn't count on it, sadly. Blizzard seems obsessed with Security by Obscurity.